# How to count how many times a pandas row appears based only on certain columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like the one below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"firstname": ["John", "Myla", "Lewis", "John", "Myla"],
                   "lastname": ['Smith', 'Anderson', 'Werner', 'Smith', 'Lewis'],
                   "ignore_var": [24, np.nan, 21, 99, 26]})
```

I am trying to see based only in the first two columns (*firstname* and *lastname*) how many times each author appears. In my example, everyone including *Myla* appears one time except for *John* who appears 2 time. I would like to add this as df['count']

```
df.groupby(['firstname', 'lastname']).size()
# there is also count() in case it is preferred
```

I manage to do the aggregation and the count. How can I lastly merge it to the original dataframe?

I would like to keep all rows and simply add it as an extra column.

Comment: `df['count'] = df.groupby(['firstname', 'lastname'])['firstname'].transform('size')`

Comment: exactly what I needed! Can you explain the solution, i.e. further elaborate and I will accept it. I would like to understand it and learn

Comment: There should be quite a few questions on SO on `groupby().transform()`. Also it should be straightforward from [the official document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html).